# r grep 'n' characters after and before match

Tags: r, string

I have a .XML file retrieved from Pubmed. Now, I would like to find two different 'strings/words' in every line of the file If the 'strings/words' are found then would like to retrieve the matching 'strings/words' along with 'n' number of characters before and after the match.

For example, if the string to be searched is 'string' in the following line and I want 10 characters before and after match string.

"The rest of the string is actually really useful"

I should get;

"st of the file is actual"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just "pad" your regular expression to tell it to grab the 10 character before and after

```
x <- "The rest of the string is actually really useful"
stringr::str_extract(x, ".{0,10}string.{0,10}")
# [1] "st of the string is actual"
```

The `.` stands for any character and `{0,10}` means to match up to 10 characters (so if you were to grab "rest" that doesn't have 10 whole character to the left, it will still match).

Comment: Thank you so much MrFlick. It really worked. One more thing, can you suggest how can I search for 2 strings like in the above example 'string' OR 'actually'?

Comment: You should probably spend time reading about regular expressions. They aren't specific to R. There are many options. You can use "|" for OR-style matches `stringr::str_extract(x, ".{0,10}(string|actually).{0,10}")` but it's less clear how you want to handle multiple matches per string. You'll probably find more suggestions if you search this site for existing questions as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `regmatches`

```
 regmatches(x,regexpr(".{1,10}string.{1,10}",x))
[1] "st of the string is actual"
```

Comment: Thank you Onyambu

Comment: @AmitAgrey what does that mean?

Comment: Related to your above suggestion, What if I would want to search for multiple strings like string1 OR string2 OR string3 and want to pass the search as a vector like; searchstring <- c('database','registry','registries'). 
I tried regmatches(x,regexpr(".{1,10}(searchstring).{1,10}",x)) but it didn't work.

Comment: I see what you mean. try `sapply(paste0("(.{1,10}",searchstring,".{1,10})"),function(i)regmatches(x,gregexpr(i,x)))`. Although given an example you can find the correct regexp with no for loop